# Cannot figure out how to reference Scanner object in different class

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting my program to run interactively.

In one of the classes the `System.in` is being changed to read from a text file like so:

```
public class mainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      ...
        try {System.setIn(new java.io.FileInputStream("foo.txt"));} 
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {}
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        someClass instance = new someClass(sc);
      ...
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is in my other class. I don't know how to call point or reference to this same scanner.

EDIT:

Alright so my class accepts a scanner as an argument. Is there a way to call that variable in a method later on?

```
public someClass (Scanner sc)
{

}

public void test(String a)
{
   someClass.sc.nextLine();
}
```

When I try something like this I get an error saying it cannot find variable sc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference the same `Scanner` object unless you pass that reference to the other class or to some instance of it.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass(sc);
```

the `Scanner` instance is passed as an argument to the constructor of `SomeClass`. You can save that reference in a variable and reuse it when you need.

Comment: Alright so my class accepts a scanner as an argument. Is there a way to call that variable in a method later on?
`public someClass (Scanner sc){}`
`public void test(String a){
someClass.sc.nextLine();
}`
I get an error if I try to call it this way.

Comment: @user2840824 Please update your answer with the new code. Before you proceed, please read the [java tutorial on classes and objects.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: Alright I have updated the above code and looking at that tutorial now.

Comment: @user2840824 So go through the link I posted. Variables have scope. You need to assign the reference of `sc` in the constructor to a member field. You can then use that member in your other instance method.

Comment: You must save the scanner to a local variable-- right now, it's being passed in and then lost when the constructor exits.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the help I was able to get it to work correctly. Appreciate the help and the knowledge.